# cURL PHP request without flash

Tags: php, html, flash, curl

I would like to get the source of one of a page with a flash/html5 video player. If I use the normal curl request, I only get the flash code, but I want to get the html5 video code.

Is it possible to change the header (I already tried to change the x-flash-version in the header, but it doesn't work) or something to say the javascript,which checks, whether Iam using flash, that Iam not using flash?

Thank you in advance,
Noro

Comment: Can we see some code.  I'm not really sure what you are asking.  Can you just use file_get_contents()?

Answer (score 0):

Without a URL of the page that you are trying to get the HTML for it is hard to know how the page is deciding whether to render HTML video code or flash code.

It is very likely that JavaScript on the page is changing the DOM at the time to support the Video tags.

If you have a browser that renders with video tags then look at the headers being sent in the POST / GET request and match those headers in your curl call. You can experiment by using the -H flag to the curl command line to send different headers until you get the result you need.